# Django Admin Filtering List By TextField

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I need to filter an admin list based on a TextField. I want to be able to filter the queryset for all objects whose TextField value is Null.

I tried the following:

```
 def filter_for_field(self, request, queryset):

    queryset=queryset.exclude(field__isnull=True)
    return queryset
```

I added that as a method to my AdminModel and then added the property "actions=['filter_for_field'].

I also tried to do it without a return statement, no dice.  The action is showing up in the admin but it is not removing objects with a null value for the TextField.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [custom FilterSpec](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) functionality to create custom admin filter. It is available in the SVN version of Django right now and planned for [Django 1.4](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django/en/latest/releases/1.4.html#list-filters-in-admin-interface).

```
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class IsNullFilter(SimpleListFilter):
   # Human-readable title which will be displayed in the
   # right admin sidebar just above the filter options.
   title = _('Custom filter')

   # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
   parameter_name = 'custom_filter'

   def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
       """
       Returns a list of tuples. The first element in each
       tuple is the coded value for the option that will
       appear in the URL query. The second element is the
       human-readable name for the option that will appear
       in the right sidebar.
       """
       return (
           ('True', _('is Null')),
           ('False', _('is not Null')),
       )

   def queryset(self, request, queryset):
       """
       Returns the filtered queryset based on the value
       provided in the query string and retrievable via
       `self.value()`.
       """

       if self.value() == 'True':
           return queryset.filter(costomfield__isnull=True)
       if self.value() == 'True':
           return queryset.filter(costomfield__isnull=False)
```

Then you need to pass it in `ModelAdmin.list_filter`:

```
class CustomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (IsNullFilter,)
```